# ubuntu iptables libvirt port forwarding

Tags: iptables, kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-16.04, libvirt

I have been beating my head against the wall for the past few days trying to figure out how to allow incoming connections to a vm machine on ports 443 and 8443.

Here is some information on the system.

**ifconfig before VM is started**

```
ens3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fa:16:3e:7a:fd:c3
          inet addr:x.x.x.45  Bcast:x.x.x.45  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1809 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1673 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:145652 (145.6 KB)  TX bytes:130509 (130.5 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:808 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:808 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:74740 (74.7 KB)  TX bytes:74740 (74.7 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:c4:48:90
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:53 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:40 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:4071 (4.0 KB)  TX bytes:6578 (6.5 KB)

virbr1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:9f:72:7f
          inet addr:192.168.42.1  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1077 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:917 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:695843 (695.8 KB)  TX bytes:169696 (169.6 KB)
```

**ifconfig after VM is started**

```
ens3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fa:16:3e:7a:fd:c3
          inet addr:x.x.x.45  Bcast:x.x.x.45  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2026 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1902 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:162734 (162.7 KB)  TX bytes:153951 (153.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1296 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1296 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:121712 (121.7 KB)  TX bytes:121712 (121.7 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:c4:48:90
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:96 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:73 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:7526 (7.5 KB)  TX bytes:12615 (12.6 KB)

virbr1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:9f:72:7f
          inet addr:192.168.42.1  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2118 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1792 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1386531 (1.3 MB)  TX bytes:333696 (333.6 KB)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:ee:5c:d0
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:feee:5cd0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:43 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:83 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:4057 (4.0 KB)  TX bytes:8869 (8.8 KB)

vnet1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:0b:15:eb
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fe0b:15eb/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1041 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:936 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:705262 (705.2 KB)  TX bytes:167544 (167.5 KB)
```

**iptables -S**

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr1 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr1 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i virbr1 -o virbr1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o virbr1 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i virbr1 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o virbr1 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
```

**iptables -L**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
```

**VM ifconfig**

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:0F:C1:9D:47
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:fff:fec1:9d47/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:230 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:216 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:19661 (19.2 KiB)  TX bytes:28440 (27.7 KiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:EE:5C:D0
          inet addr:192.168.122.135  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:feee:5cd0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:63 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:73 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:312 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:7723 (7.5 KiB)  TX bytes:6469 (6.3 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:0B:15:EB
          inet addr:192.168.42.201  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe0b:15eb/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:914 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:759 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:3960 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:157257 (153.5 KiB)  TX bytes:690751 (674.5 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:22041 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:22041 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:40447910 (38.5 MiB)  TX bytes:40447910 (38.5 MiB)

veth159e182 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:8A:03:66:BA:E3
          inet6 addr: fe80::508a:3ff:fe66:bae3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:203 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:205 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:20046 (19.5 KiB)  TX bytes:18696 (18.2 KiB)
```

**I have tried the following**

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.135:443
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.135:8443
iptables -I FORWARD -o virbr0 -d  192.168.122.135 -j ACCEPT
```

**Also tried this**

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.42.201:443
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.42.201:8443
iptables -I FORWARD -o virbr0 -d  192.168.42.201 -j ACCEPT
```

When I try to connect to the server with chrome the ip address gets changed to the local ip address. Please see images.

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B175.jpg)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H59OO.jpg)

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your web application is doing this, not the firewall.

Because you're running OpenShift Origin behind NAT, you need to set `openshift_master_cluster_public_hostname` to the address from which it can be reached on the outside. See the [documentation](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/advanced_install.html#cluster-variables-table) for other variables you may need to set.